# Effective resistance of a plate with varying conductance

Tags: electromagnetism

I'm trying to find the resistance across a plate made up of different materials. Do my formulas and method make sense - will they yield the correct answer?

Reference I'm using: http://web.mit.edu/6.013_book/www/chapter7/7.2.html

I'm starting with equation (3) for the voltage/potential in a material with varying conductance, setting Φ = 1 at one edge, and to 0 at the other for the boundary conditions:
$$
\nabla\ \cdot\ \sigma \nabla \Phi\ = 0
$$

Right now, I'm solving this numerically with Mathematica. Once I get the solution for Φ, I just use $$J = \sigma \nabla\Phi$$ to get the current density.

Then I just integrate along one of the edges of the platter to find the total current:

$$
I = \int_{edge} J  dx
$$

And finally find the resistance with R=I/V.....

Should that work? Thanks for any advice/pointers/solutions, thanks!

Comment: The quantity you're calculating is not just effective. It is *the* resistance.

Comment: Indeed to solve this your main difficulty is solving the PDE in the first place. Calculating the total current is then sort of a trivial afterthought. To numerically solve I would recommend finite volume method solvers such as FiPy.

Comment: Well, like I said, I'm a little rusty on the terminology ;p Thanks for the advice though. I'm using Mathematica, it seems to be working OK. Updated question to be a little clearer.

Comment: Well, I can put an official Answer but it would simply be "Yes." :-)  Your approach should indeed work.

Comment: Restance?  Do you want to edit the title?

Comment: Ooops! Fixed it.